# Overriding properties in Spring Cloud Dataflow stream definition

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

For Kafka streams (consumers) that use KafkaAvroDeserializer I need to override some configs on deployment with --propertiesFile to work. KafkaBinder 1.1.1 added this config option.

I prefer not to use deployment properties if I can, because they're not visible on the dashboard and it's dangerous if another user decides to stop and restart a stream without setting the properties. Is it possible to include these properties within the stream definition? My repeated attempts have failed to work. I don't see an example of this on the reference doc.

e.g. for yaml equivalent:

```
<...>
binder:
  configuration:
    value.deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
    schema.registry.url: http://my.dns.com:8081
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify those Spring Cloud Stream properties in Data Flow Stream definition DSL like this:

> stream create a1 --definition "time --spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.value.serializer=serializer | log --spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.value.deserializer=deserializer --spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.schema.registry.url='http://myregistry'" --deploy

Comment: Any way to pass in a file of standard properties?  Since the DSL doesn't allow multiple lines, it's quite ridiculous to repeat this for every app in every stream. (Unless I'm missing something)

Comment: Hi, You can use --propertiesFile option to use YAML or properties file that can have all your properties.

Comment: You can refer the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/spring-cloud-dataflow-create-stream.html#_inline_vs_file_reference_properties_2

Comment: Thanks, but from the documentation it looks like --propertiesFile is an option for `stream deploy` which is what the original question here was asking to try to avoid for reasons stated.  Is there such an option for `stream create`?

Comment: ok, I forgot about your original question when replying above. Specifying the file based properties at `stream create` isn't supported yet. One other possible approach is to use common application properties: http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/spring-cloud-dataflow-stream-advanced.html#spring-cloud-dataflow-global-properties. But this gets applied to all the applications. Please feel free to create a feature request based on your requirement here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues.